# How to exclude part of alternative from capture?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, pcre, regular-language

There is an regex: `((?:description|speed|type|peers)\s+set|classify)`.
How to exclude `\s+set` from capture group?

There must be only `description` or `speed` or `type` or `peers` or `classify`.

We can do it so:

```
pattern = '^\s+"([A-Za-z]+)\.([_A-Za-z0-9-]+)"\s+"([^\s]+)"\s+((description|speed|type|peers)\s+set|classify)\s+"?(.+)"?'
p = re.compile(pattern)
path = 'some_file'
fd = open(path)
for l in fd.readlines():
    m = p.search(l)
    if not m:
        continue
    g = m.groups()
    if g[4]:
        (region, host, interface, cmd, value) = g[0].lower(), g[1].lower(), g[2].lower(), g[4], g[5]
    else:
        (region, host, interface, cmd, value) = g[0].lower(), g[1].lower(), g[2].lower(), g[3], g[5]
```

But it is ugly...

```
if g[4]:
    (region, host, interface, cmd, value) = g[0].lower(), g[1].lower(), g[2].lower(), g[4], g[5]
else:
    (region, host, interface, cmd, value) = g[0].lower(), g[1].lower(), g[2].lower(), g[3], g[5]
```

How to cut `\s+set` witihin regex engine and have only one line in code:

`(region, host, interface, cmd, value) = g[0].lower(), g[1].lower(), g[2].lower(), g[3], g[4]`
?

Comment: Have you tried using lookarounds?

Comment: Hi. I tried use ^\s+"([A-Za-z]+)\.([_A-Za-z0-9-]+)"\s+"([^\s]+)"\s+((description|speed|type|peers)(?=\s+set)|classify)\s+"?(.+)"?'

Comment: but 'set' falls to last group...

Comment: I recommend you use something like https://regex101.com/#python to help you develop your expressions. You might also consider trying to do less in one big step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't mind multiple capture groups (and therefore slightly altering the rest of the code), it's super easy - just do the opposite of what you're doing.

`(?:(description|speed|type|peers)\s+set|(classify))` as seen in https://regex101.com/r/bR1nV7/1

If you don't want it, you can use lookarounds. `((?:description|speed|type|peers)(?=\s+set)|classify)` as seen in https://regex101.com/r/bR1nV7/2

There is no "exclude this thing" in regex because the other tools like non-capture groups and lookarounds do it for you.